# Dirac function series expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion, dirac-delta

Dirac function is generalized function. However, is it possible to use taylor expansion on it? i.e., is it possible to write
$$\delta(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}x^{n}$$?

I know that it can have Fourier transform and can be represented as Legendre polynomial, but I would like to know if it can written in terms of Taylor and corresponding $A_{n}$.

Comment: Well, the Dirac delta fails to be a function near zero, much less an analytic function...

Comment: Is it possible to write it as a taylor series? If it can be represented as fourier series, I think it is possible to write it in taylor as well.

Comment: Okay, here is another hint: A power series which converges around $0$ defines an analytic function near $0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee  The context is the space of distributions. I believe the OP understands that the Dirac distribution is not a power series in the classical sense. Try answering this question: is the proposed equality valid in the Schwartz space of distributions?

Comment: Is it possible to have it in distribution sense?

Comment: @uniquesolution The standard formula for the coefficients yields $A_n=\delta^{(n)}(0)/n!$, which you'll have a hard time evaluating. I can't think of any weak sense in which the delta function would have a Taylor series, however.

Comment: @uniquesolution, You have a valid point :) Now the question sounds much more interesting...

Comment: We have the formal identity $\delta(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i} (z+1)^n$ (a formal Laurent series centered at -1), which finds applications in the theory of [vertex operator algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_operator_algebra). More generally, we have $\delta(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{t^{-n-1}}{2\pi i} (z+t)^n$ for $t \neq 0$. But as far as I know there is no expansion of the form $\delta(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} A_n z^n$, let alone one where $A_n=0$ for all $n<0$.

Answer (score 4):

Whether you use the limit approach suggested by @pointguardo or anything else, you need to provide the identity:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) dx = 1.
$$
If $\delta$ admits a Taylor expansion, then
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty A_n \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n dx = 1.
$$
Because of the symmetry of $(-\infty, \infty)$ w.r.t. $x  = 0$, integrals with odd powers vanish and we have
$$
2\sum_{n = 0}^\infty A_{2n}  \int_0^\infty x^{2n} dx = 1.
$$
The integral is nothing else but the Mellin transform of $1$, which is equal to
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{2n} dx = \delta(2n).
$$
Thus, we arrive at
$$
2 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty A_{2n} \delta(2n) = 1.
$$
When $n \neq 0$, $\delta(2n) = 0$. Therefore, the only non-zero term is
$$
2 A_0 \delta(0) = 1, 
$$
which does not hold for any $A_0$.

Thus, the answe is: no.

Comment: I see. I think it is ok at first since it can have representation of Fourier cosine, which should be able to have Taylor series solution. Btw, if I use the idea that expressing Fourier cosine first then series expansion on cosine formula, is it ok?

Comment: Whatever method you choose, the defintion of the Dirac distribution requires that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) dx = 1$. In my opinion, even if you use the representation you mentioned, you will come up with the impossibility to satisfy this integral identity.

Comment: What I come up with that the coefficients are unbounded.

Comment: You mean $A_n$?

Comment: Yes. I find out this problem

Comment: I am wondeing how did you manage.

Comment: I use expansion of Fourier cosine, then expressing cosine into Taylor. Assuming the summation sign can be interchanged, I come up with a Taylor expansion for delta. However, the coefficient $A_{n}$ would be unbounded. Of course, I need to ensure that the summation sign can be interchanged, but since it is just a trial, I do this to see what happen.

Comment: How do you deal with the constraint $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) dx =1$? Maybe you can add your answer.

Comment: Doesn't this proof imply any function integrable from -infinity to infinity does not admit a Taylor expansion?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you explain how come "The integral is nothing else but the Mellin transform of 1". What you are saying appears to me to be at odds with what is written in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform. Namely, the Mellin transform is not defined for a polynomial function $x^{s+1}$ for $x \in (0,\infty)$. I suggest you clarify that what you are doing is valid within the framework of the Mellin transform.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series for Dirac delta function:
$$
\delta(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n x^n. 
$$
At any point $x \neq 0, ~ A_n \equiv 0$ for all $n \ge 0$. So, the series could be useful for the case when $x = 0$. Let's write down using straightforward definition of Taylor series.
$$
\delta(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\delta^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n. 
$$
For Dirac function the following relation is true (try to prove it!): $x\delta^{(n)}(x) = -n \delta^{(n-1)}(x)$, so using this recurrent relation one finds:
$$
\delta(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\delta^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n = \delta(0) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \underbrace{(-1)^n\left[\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\delta(x)}{x^n}\right]}_{A_n} x^n 
$$
However, I don't see how this is going to help you, since you have $\delta(0)$ as a summand which is itself an infinity.

Another approach that comes to mind (and potentially could be useful) is to try to use the limit definition of Dirac function, namely 
$$
\delta(x) = \lim_{a \to 0}\delta_a(x), 
$$
where $\delta_a(x) = \frac{1}{a\sqrt{\pi}}{e^{-x^2/a^2}}$. From here you can expand this *smooth* function in Taylor series and get the Taylor for $\delta(x)$ as a limit.

Comment: Your second approach seems to be more relyable than the first one.

Comment: I try to express it into Fourier series first (cosine function) then express cosine function into taylor, but the coefficients diverge.

Comment: Another method I try is from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.0747.pdf, equation (7) and (8). Again, the coefficients is infinty.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not possible to find a Dirac delta function representing Taylor series in the *real field* however, as Jacques Hadamard once said, things change when you *complexify i.e. transport to the complex domain* the problem you are dealing with. Considering $\delta(x)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ as an *analytic functional* or as a *residue current*, it is possible to find its representative as a very simple Laurent series and an associated real Taylor series with complex coefficients, which overcomes the issues raised by the very basic observation by Asatur Khurshudyan.

Following Gel'fand and Shilov (1964) (ch. II, §1.5 pp. 161-162), calling $\mathscr{A}(\mathbb{R})$ is the spaces of all entire functions $\psi(s)$, $s=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
|s|^q|\psi(s)|\leq C_q e^{a|y|}\quad q\in\mathbb{N}
$$
we can define $\delta(x)$ by the following formula
$$
\psi(0)=\langle \delta,\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\int\limits_{-\infty+ai}^{+\infty+ai}\frac{\psi(s)}{s}\mathrm{d}s-\int\limits_{-\infty-ai}^{+\infty-ai}\frac{\psi(s)}{s}\mathrm{d}s\right]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{|s|=1}\frac{\psi(s)}{s}\mathrm{d}s
\quad a>0\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
In this approach we can say that
$$
\delta(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}A_ns^n=s^{-1}=\frac{1}{x+iy}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(iy)^{n+1}}x^n\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
and already we see that the issue raised by Asatur Khurshudyan is avoided. Approaching the problem in $\mathscr{A}^\prime(\mathbb{R})$ could seem a limited way to deal with it: however, the same approach can be extended to  $\mathscr{D}^\prime(\mathbb{R})$ by understanding \eqref{1} in the sense of residue currents, as done by Berenstein et al. (1993) (ch. 1,§1, pp. 1-2). Following their approach, it is possible to define the following functional:
$$
I(\varphi, \epsilon)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{|s|=\epsilon}\frac{\varphi(s)}{s}\mathrm{d}s \qquad\forall\varphi\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})
$$
and by their **proposition 1.1** (Berenstein et al. (1993), ch. 1, §1, p.2) we have that
$$
\varphi(0)=\langle \delta,\varphi\rangle=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}I(\varphi, \epsilon)\triangleq\mathrm{res}_{x=0}\frac{\varphi(s)}{s}\qquad\forall\varphi\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})
$$

[1] Berenstein, C. A.; Gay, R.; Vidras, A.; Yger, A. (1993), *Residue currents and Bezout identities*, Progress in Mathematics, 114, Basel–Berlin–Boston: Birkhäuser Verlag, pp. xi+158, doi:10.1007/978-3-0348-8560-7, ISBN 3-7643-2945-9 / 0-8176-2945-9 / 978-3-0348-8560-7, MR 1249478, Zbl 0802.32001.

[2] Gel'fand, I. M.; Shilov, G. E. (1964) [1958], *Generalized functions. Vol. I: Properties and operations*, New York–London: Academic Press, pp. xviii+423, ISBN 978-0-12-279501-5, MR 0166596, Zbl 0115.33101.

Comment: What is $y$ in Eq. (2) and how do you find it?

My view is as follows. Let $\delta$ admits Taylor expansion. Then, $$ \delta(x) = A_0 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty A_n x^n$$. Since $A_0$ and $A_n$ are constants, it seems impossible to implement $\delta(x) = 0$ for all $x \neq 0$. Apparently, for $x = 2$ and $x = 4$ we then would have $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^n A_n = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^n (2^n A_n).$$ I am not sure if this leads to a reasonable result even for a complexified $A_n$.

Comment: $y$ is the imaginary part of the complex argument of the representative function (indicatrix) of $\delta(x)$, as an analytic functional: it can be chosen arbitrarily, requiring only $y\neq 0$. I understand (and like) your approach to a negative solution of the problem, and I think *it rules out the possibility of having a Taylor expansion for $\delta$ in the real field*: however, I circumvent the problem by posing $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)\mathrm{d}x\equiv\mathrm{res}\int\limits_{|s|=1}\frac{1}{s}\mathrm{d}s,$$ so you cannot integrate eq. (2) termwise respect to only $x$.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan, I apologize for not placing the tag in my previous comment, but I was running out of characters. My approach is based on the fact that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)\mathrm{d}x$$ is a formal expression for $\delta$ which can be susbtituted by another formal expression $$ \mathrm{res}\int\limits_{|s|=1} \frac{1}{s}\mathrm{d}s$$  which can be used to construct a "parameter dependent" Taylor expansion respect to the real variable $x$, under some very weak assumptions and by careful interpretation of the operations that can be performed on it.

Comment: How you get $\delta(x) = 0$ for $x \neq 0$ from Eq. (2) for arbitrary $y$?

Comment: This is again a matter of interpretation of (2): if $x\in\mathrm{supp}\varphi(x)$ and $x\neq 0$, then $$\langle\delta,\varphi\rangle=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int\limits_{|s-x|=\epsilon}\frac{\varphi(s)}{s}\mathrm{d}s=0.$$ Again, each operation performed to the "Taylor series expansion" of $\delta$ should be carefully interpreted in the context of complex analysis and residue theory: and $\delta$ cannot be considered as an ordinary function even in this context.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan: I apologize again for forgotting to place a tag for you in the above comment. I am having a busy time.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in physics, the Taylor expansion of the Dirac delta often appears. The concept is still obscure to me and I was hoping to find an answer to give me a better insight. We can find in numerous scientific article an expression equivalent to

$\begin{equation}
\delta (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{u}) = \delta(\mathbf{r}) - \mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla \delta(\mathbf{r}) + \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \nabla \delta(\mathbf{r}) \cdot \mathbf{u} + O(3)
\end{equation}$

where r is an atomic position and u is a small displacement due to a perturbation applied to the atom. So to answer your question, is it possible to represent a $\delta(x)$ as a Taylor series: Yes and it gives sensible results in physics.

Now, you can push further and ask the question : Is the $\delta(x)$ function correctly represented or is it only a trick ?

For this, I've made a python code. Note that, I've approximated the delta dirac function as a gaussian. Remember that one of the definition of a delta dirac is a gaussian with $\lim\limits_{a=0}\sigma=a$. According to me, this function seems to converge with enough terms and an infinitely small sigma. This gives the following plot and I've linked the code if you want to play with sigma to convince yourself :

[image: Taylor series of a gaussian up to second order term. The position is at r=0.5 and the displacement is u=0.1.]

```
def gaussian_delta():
# Define the parameters of the Gaussian function
sigma = 0.1  # standard deviation
r0 = 0.5     # center position

# Define the displacement vector
u = np.array(0.1)

# Define the x-axis range for plotting
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)

# Define the Gaussian function
G = lambda r: np.exp(-0.5*((r-r0)/sigma)**2)

# Define the first three terms of the Taylor series
term1 = lambda r: G(r)
term2 = lambda r: G(r) - u.dot(np.gradient(G(r), r))
term3 = lambda r: G(r) - u.dot(np.gradient(G(r), r)) + 0.5 * u.dot(np.gradient(np.gradient(G(r), r),r)).dot(u)

# Plot the functions
plt.plot(x, term1(x), color='b', label="Term 1")
plt.plot(x, term2(x), color='g', label="Term 1+2")
plt.plot(x, term3(x), color='y', label="Term 1+2+3")
plt.plot(x, np.zeros_like(x), 'r', label="Delta Dirac")

plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-0.2,1.4)

# For axvline, 0|1 correspond to the bottom|top of the graph
ymin = ((0-plt.ylim()[0])/(plt.ylim()[1]-plt.ylim()[0]))
plt.axvline(r0+u, color='r', ymin=ymin, ymax=1)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```